# fetch records between n and n+6 with condition mysql php

Tags: php, mysql

i am trying to fetch records between n and n+6 means from last fetch id to next 6 records. for example

```
$id = 0 ; 

SELECT * FROM foo WHERE id BETWEEN($id+1)AND($id+6)

result id: 1 , 2 ,3 , 4, 5, 6
```

working perfect, if i want to use condition like `WHERE NUMBER_OF_ORDERS = 10`

```
Result would be : 3,5,7,11,15,16
```

Now if want to fetch records from last id to id+6, due to random records. its not working. below is my code.

```
SELECT * FROM foo WHERE id BETWEEN($id+1)AND($id+6) AND NUMBER_OF_ORDERS = 10
```

its not working

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: What result is your last query giving ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may try using LIMIT instead of condition on id field;

```
SELECT * 
FROM foo 
WHERE id > ($id) AND NUMBER_OF_ORDERS = 10
ORDER BY id ASC
LIMIT 6
```